# Failed to Process session due to could not read from StandardFlowFileRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

I am evaluating NiFi and have created a basic workflow, It listens a SFTP directory, apply some transformations and then put the flow in Cassandra, But while spliting message I am getting below error.

Failed to Process session due to could not read from StandardFlowFileRecord

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace of the error from nifi-app.log

Comment: SplitText[id=914f3477-9a07-3433-8a28-6baf6f1a9b2a] SplitText[id=914f3477-9a07-3433-8a28-6baf6f1a9b2a] failed to process session due to Could not read from 

StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=6626d382-4e6b-4f1c-9bb4-fd9647f0a351,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1569417721885-1998928, 

container=default, section=80], offset=944007, length=7244],offset=0,name=[EUtranCellFDD]_[LD11342]_[A20190925.1700].csv,size=7244]